# How to add extra HTTP variables dynamically in jQuery datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery datatables for showing search results. I have some checkboxes which are used to filter results. That means, I have to send extra HTTP get variables to the server when the checkboxes are checked. How do I do that dynamically?

I am aware that extra HTTP variables can be added using `fnServerParams`, but it can be added only at the time of init of the datatable.

How do I add/remove HTTP variables on the event of checking/unchecking a checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because fnServerParams is a function, it will be executed each time an Ajax request is sent to the server. So the parameters are added dynamically at the time of the request, rather than at initialisation time. So I think that fnServerParams is exactly what you need :-)

Allan

Comment: You are right Allan. fnServerParams is called before each ajax request. But I solved this problem by using the fnSettings function and modified the sAjaxSource. I know it is inelegant. but it worked. Thanks for your answer. I will change my code as per your suggestion.